# Integral $\int^{1}_{-1} \frac{\ln(ax^2+2bx+a)}{x^2+1}dx$ if $a>b>0$

Tags: integration

I am trying to evaluate the following integral:

$$\int^{1}_{-1} \frac{\ln(ax^2+2bx+a)}{x^2+1}dx,$$  where $a>b>0$.

I can't really think of a way to find it. So, please give me a hint.

Comment: you could do the following:
write $\log((ax)^2+bx+a)$ as $\log([x-x_-])+\log([x-x_+])$ and use partial fraction for $\frac{1}{(1+x^2)}$. Afterwards integrate every of the four resulting terms separately. Unfortunately the result will look messy anyways :(.

Answer (score 5):

With $\sin\theta =\frac ba$\begin{align}
&\int^{1}_{-1} \frac{\ln(ax^2+2bx+a)}{x^2+1}dx\\
=& \int^{1}_{-1} \frac{\ln a}{x^2+1}dx+ 
 \int^{1}_{-1} \frac{\ln(x^2+2x \sin \theta+1)}{x^2+1}\overset{x\to1/x}{dx}\\
=& \ \frac\pi2\ln a+\frac12 \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{\ln(x^2+2x \sin \theta+1)}{x^2+1}dx-2\int_1^\infty \frac{\ln x}{x^2+1}dx\\
= &\ \frac\pi2\ln a+\frac\pi2 \ln\left(2\cos\frac\theta2\right)-2G\\
=& \ \frac\pi2\ln2 +\frac\pi2 \ln\left( \sqrt{a^2-b^2}+a\right)-2G
\end{align}

Comment: how did you made the limits to infinity? sorry if i am missing some theorems

Comment: @hemantkumar - first $\int_{-1}^1= \int_{-1}^0 + \int_{0}^1$, then $x\to 1/x$ for both

Comment: Why $\sin (\theta) = b/a$ ? How you know $b/a$ belongs to $[-1,1]$?

Comment: @An_Elephant Because, $a>b>0$.

Comment: @lonestudent     Suppose $a=2$ and $b=1$ . Then $b/a$ does not equal $\sin \theta$?

Comment: @An_Elephant Take $\theta =\frac {\pi}{6}$.

Comment: @Quanto how did you integrated $\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}$ to get $\frac{\pi}{2}ln(2cos(\theta/2))$

Comment: @hemantkumar - Feymann’s trick: $I(\theta)= \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{\ln(x^2+2x \sin \theta+1)}{x^2+1}dx$ and $I’(\theta)=-\pi\tan\frac\theta2$

Comment: @lonestudent So this answer will only work for which $|a/b|\le1$